# In Corona, I need help moving a character to one of three points by swipe

Tags: coronasdk, distance, swipe

When a user swipes the screen, I need the player to move to specific position.  So, if the player is in the center of the screen, and the user swipes left, the x position is -100.  If the user swipes right again, the player would move back to center.  Another swipe right would put the x position at + 100.  A swipe right would do nothing from that point, but a swipe left would move them back to center  See below for text visual:  Any help would be **GREATLY APPRECIATED**!

---

```
  swipe    swipe
  <---->  <---->

X        X        X
```

---

Comment: Are you having problems with the logic or with the implementation?

Comment: Hi Paul,The logic of the code...I'm more versed with Javascript...and so I keep learning Lua a little on the side every now and again.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing "swipe" is pretty easy, but you have to understand touch handlers and the different event phases and the data passed to the handler to make a lot of sense for this.

A swipe is nothing more than a touch that moves in a direction and then the app responds to the action.  This is similar to dragging, but a drag moves the object with the touch.  The basic touch handler is something like this:

```
 local LEFT = 50
 local CENTER = display.contentCenterX
 local RIGHT = display.contentWidth - 50

 local object = display.newCircle( display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY, 25 )

 local function handleSwipe( event )
      if event.phase == "moved" then
           local dX = event.x - event.xStart
           print(event.x, event.xStart, dX)
           if dX > 10 then
                -- swipe right
                local spot = RIGHT
                if event.target.x == LEFT then
                     spot = CENTER
                end
                transition.to( event.target, {time=500, x = spot } )
           elseif dX  < -10 then
                -- swipe left
                local spot = LEFT
                if event.target.x == RIGHT then
                     spot = CENTER
                end
                transition.to( event.target, {time=500, x = spot } )
           end
       end
       return true
 end

 object:addEventListener( "touch", handleSwipe )
```

Now I used 10 px of touch movement to do this, but I normally use 5px of touch movement, adjust to taste.